# How to structure User - Team - Project model Django (ManyToMany)

Tags: django

I'm hoping someone can give me a push in the right direction, at least conceptually. What I'm trying to achieve; a model where:

- You have users, workstreams and projects;
- Workstream should always be linked to a project (i.e. they exist "in" projects)
- Users can be linked to a project without being a workstream;
- Users can be in multiple teams and projects

I've read something about Models Managers before, should I use these?

Something else I'm struggling with is that users can/should be linked to projects directly or though a team, will this cause problems?

below some snippets from the models.py file

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Workstream(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User) #Like this?


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User) #Like this?
```

Any help in the right directions will be greatly appreaciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not advisable to link users directly to a project if it is possible to link teams to the same project. It would be possible for a given user to be two times in a Project, as a individual user or as part of a team, and you would have to search for Users and Users inside Teams when looking for all Users linked to a Project, which is cumbersome. Or if a Workstream represents a task to be done inside a Project, it wouldn't make sense to have a User that is not inside a task to be done.

I don't know the specifics of your project, but maybe each User would join a Team that is already part of a Project. A User could join a Team and be the sole member.

```
class Workstream(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User)

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

An admin could assign a Team to a Project or a user that has a 'project leader' privilege could assign a Team to a Project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Preferably I'd also offer the possibility for a user to join a project without a team/workstream (in case there is a project without teams/workstreams), but I guess I'll just stick with forced creation of 1 team/workstream when adding a new project

Comment: What is the best way to get all members of a project with this structure? I want to have a page where I show all project and for each project display all members of that project